# Audiovisual Vocabulary

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I was wondering if anyone had a link to a bunch of German vocabulary, both audio, and visual. I am an intermediate to upper-intermediate learner who is looking to expand vocabulary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Pons* has a [Bildwörterbuch](http://bildworterbuch.com/) that might help you. It has both the images and some words have a pronunciation link.

On the other hand, since German spelling represents very faithfully every phoneme (or seen in the opposite direction, German reads regularly), you wouldn't need to hear independently every word.  Just learn the rules; they are incredibly easy.